# updating mysql table with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, twitch

I want to update one of my columns when it finds the user already in the database.

This is `viewers = ['freddiejefferson']`

Table:

```
kong_plays           10
freddiejefferson     10
```

My code:

```
function getPoints(){
              for (viewerCount = viewerAmount; viewerCount >= 0; viewerCount--) {
                currentViewer = viewers[viewerCount]
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM points WHERE twitchName = currentViewer", (err, result) => {

                  if(err) throw err; 
                  if (result === ''){
                    connection.query("INSERT INTO points (twitchName, points) VALUES (currentViewer, '10')", (err, result) => {
                      if(err) throw err;
                      console.log("Inserted into table")
                    });
                  }else{
                    connection.query("UPDATE points SET points= points+10 WHERE twitchName = currentViewer", (err, result) => {
                      if(err) throw err;
                      console.log("updated points")
                    });
                  }
                });
              }

        }
```

The error it outputs :
`Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'currentViewer' in 'where clause'`

ERROR 1:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO points (twitchName, points) VALUES (" + currentViewer " +, '10')", (err, result) => {

                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   (under current viewer)

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

ERROR 2:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

 Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're querying for the string `currentViewer` while instead you want to query for whatever the variable `currentViewer` holds.

This would be done by changing the query lines to:

`connection.query("SELECT * FROM points WHERE twitchName = " + currentViewer, (err, result) => {`

The same applies to the insert statement:

`connection.query("INSERT INTO points (twitchName, points) VALUES (" + currentViewer + ", '10')", (err, result) => {`

Comment: Updated my answer. I messed up the order. Sorry.